# how to take an input of date using java swing text box and store in mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

What I Want to Do ?

I have a Class **Customers** that has a variable dob // Date of Birth

I am trying to take an input from the user using a java Swing Text Field.

Convert it into a java date and then convert into java.sql.Date, so that i can store it in my MySQL database.

This is the setter method for Customer class

```
public  void setDOB(java.sql.Date dob)
{
    DateOfBirth = dob;
}
```

Here is the code for my Swing Class(Application Window Loader)

```
//Date
            if(textField_5.getText().isEmpty())
                lblerr.setVisible(true);
            else
            {
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
                    Date dob = null;
                    dob = sdf.parse(textField_5.getText());
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dob.getTime());
                    c1.setDOB(sqlDate);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                allinfoisentered = true;
            }
```

textField_5 - is the Field Where User Inputs the Date.

I Tested My App With the following different inputs :

1. 12-12-1993
2. 10-05-1970

The Problem Is : The value that gets stored in MySQL Table is 1992-12-27, i have a strong feeling that this is some default date.

I want to know, How do i parse the string into Date and then send it to MySQL table.

Comment: Why are you catching `ParseException` but then continuing as if you've succeeded?

Comment: "dd-MM-YYYY" should be "dd-MM-yyyy". It results in a `ParseException` if you use `Y`.

Comment: How do the fields of the dob paremeter in setDOB look like? Do you still have the proper values there?

Comment: @JonSkeet i am continuing as if i've succeeded because i wanted to see whether my query is running fine or not. and it is running, my data does get in the table.

Comment: Please check the `dob` parameter in `setDOB()`. A simple `System.out.println(dob.toString())` would be sufficient (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString), so that we know which value is passed to your persistence layer.

Comment: @BheshGurung Yes changing "dd-MM-YYYY" to "dd-MM-yyyy" works, thanks allot.

Comment: @IshanKhanna: Yes, all but the one thing that you've failed to parse. It sounds like that really was the problem - **don't ignore exceptions**. I'll add an answer covering this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please do so, I'd be very thankful to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As discussed in comments...)

You have two problems:

- Your parsing format is incorrect. It should use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY"
- More importantly (IMO) your error handling is incorrect. You're using this `catch` block:

  ```
  catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

  ... which means that even if parsing fails, you'll insert all the data except the date, which wouldn't have been set. You *should* have been able to get the information from the log files anyway, but presumably either you're not logging `System.err`, or you didn't look at the logs.

Error handling is *very* important. If an exception occurs when parsing the data, I would *expect* you not to want to insert the record at all - instead, the error should be propagated up the stack, *forcing* you to take note of it, and not losing the information. So you probably wanted something like this instead:

```
catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new DataValidationException(
        "Error parsing date: " + textField_5.getText(), e);
}
```

(Where `DataValidationException` is just a made-up exception - you should consider what you want to use consistently in your app.)

Two things are vitally important when an error occurs:

- You should handle it properly at the time. Often this means aborting the current operation, although in some cases you could retry, or continue without some unimportant information.
- You should capture enough information to understand the error later.

Comment: what is the difference between e.printstacktrace and your method to log an exception ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on DataValidationException.

Comment: @IshanKhanna: It's just some sort of exception that you'd use throughout your codebase. Heck, you could use `ParseException` potentially - but do so consistently. `e.printStackTrace` is *okay* so long as you make sure you actually look at it, but you probably don't want to continue. It's generally cleaner if you use a dedicated logging API though - such as the one in java.util.logging.